# How to not display out of stock products in magento?

Tags: out-of-stock

I set the Display Out of Stock Products to No, and reindex, clear cache.
But still display.
[image]

Comment: There should also be another select in your Product Stock Options : Availability, where you can set if your product is out of stock or not. Also, can you tell us if you are using a custom theme/extension ?

Comment: Have you check store wise setting for

Comment: Amit Beza@ Display Out of Stock Products option is global and it is not store wise.:)

Comment: I reckon your theme is customized to show out of stock product.

Comment: @Adarsh Khatri yes